# Waiting for incoming connection with ide key Message on PHPStorm with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I want to install debug and integrate it with PhpStorm.

I went through all the steps needed.
I add this lines to php.ini file:

```
zend_extension = "D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable= true
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

this is my created debugger screenshot :

[image]

And this is screenshot of my breakpoint on index method of a Controller named HomeController:

[image]

And this is xdebug section on php_info() page:

[image]

But every time I press Debug Button in phpStorm , home page open complete as a address like:

```
http://localhost:8000/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=17288
```

and in the debugger tab show this message like this:

```
Waiting for incoming connection with ide key '17288'
```

I research on the google and try different ways But I did not answer.

**Update** :
New I realized that Debugging via Xdebug works fine in normal Projects(no laravel). So this Problem can not be the result of PHPStorm version.
For example when Open page contain breakPoints in `localhost:8000` breakpoints ignored but when I open that page in normal form via `localhost/MyProject/public` debugging works fine.

Comment: 1) Please provide xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output captured via browser 2) Provide xdebug log -- http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: @LazyOne,I added `xdebug.remote_log="D:\xdebug.log"` option and run script but no file created and Nothing was logged.

Comment: 1) This is not xdebug section that I'm after. That one is further down and will have all current xdebug settings 2) This can mean that xdebug may not be active or did not see the debug request. try placing `xdebug_break();` in your code (programmatic breakpoint).

Comment: I add Xdebug section. `xdebug_break();` does not return anything.

Comment: xdebug_break not supposed to return anything -- it supposed to trigger the debug session. The xdebug config seems to be OK. You may also try `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`. Other than that -- try reading manuals again (I cannot say what is missing, especially since xdebug log is empty): 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/quickstart/debugger.html 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: I have got everything we need and I studied all the suggestions on the web, but problem continued. Of course I'm Using PHPStorm 10 , this new release of that May be problematic?

Comment: Doubt about that. It works fine for me (both local and remote) .. but I'm doing all debugging on Windows using IIS as web server. Maybe try changing xdebug port from default `9000` to `9001` (in both php.ini and PhpStorm settings). Otherwise -- I need to see xdebug log. If it still has nothing even after setting `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` .. then it must be some another local issue (specific to you)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have set everything correctly take care that PhpStorm will not break on the line of a method declaration (as you have done in your case).

See also http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=618

As Derick Rethans points out in the above link:

> PHP doesn't see any code on those lines, so there can not be any breakpoint. However, if you want to break on method calls, the debugging protocol implements that. I don't know whether PHPStorm provides that functionality though.

So move the breakpoint to the first executable line inside the method and try again.

Comment: I moved breakpoint to line 15 that `$latestPosts` variable exists. But again nothing happened and same Message shown.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and finally found it:
Put your break point on web.php(laravel 5.X) or route.php(laravel 4.X)
after see page "incoming connection from xdebug" just click on accept and every thing become Ok
https://murze.be/2017/01/xdebug-with-laravel-valet/